# More efficient vector comparison

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to compare 2 different vectors to catch any duplicates.  one vector is 5 million elements of 10 numbers and the other is 2.8 million of 10 elements.
My operating system is ubuntu 18.04 and I am using QtCreator.  I am getting a hangup when I try to compare these large vectors.  here is what I have tried:

```
vector<vector<int> >::iterator v1;
vector<vector<int> >::iterator v2;

for(v1 = vector1.begin(); v1 != vector1.end(); v1++)
    {
        for(v2 = vector2.begin(); v2 != vector2.end(); v2++)
        {
            if(*v1 == *v2)
            {
                vector1.erase(v1);
            }
        }
    }
```

when I try and run this and debug Qt hangs.  I am also wondering if I need to change the erase to look something like :

```
vector1.erase(v1.begin(), v1.end());
```

Any suggestions as to a "Better" way of doing this would be helpful.  I know these are some big vectors having more then 2 and a half million elements of 10 numbers.

Thx in advance

Idzireit

Still tackling the problem.  Right now I am trying a derivative of Mark Ransom's solution.  Here is what I got so far:

```
#include "includes.h"

bool vec_less(vector<int> &v1, vector<int> &v2)
{

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if(v1[i] == v2[i])
        {
            i++;
        }
        if(v1[i] < v2[i])
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    return v1.size() <v2.size();
}

void dupfilter(vector<vector<int> > &aaperms, vector<vector<int> > &perms)
{
    vector<vector<int> >::iterator v1 = aaperms.begin();
    vector<vector<int> >::iterator v2 = perms.begin();

    while(v1 != aaperms.end() && v2 != perms.end())
    {

        if(*v1 == *v2)
        {
            aaperms.erase(v1);
            ++v1;
            ++v2;
        }

        if(vec_less(*v1, *v2) == true)
            ++v1;
        else
            ++v2;
    }

    return;
}
```

I only needed to sort 1 of the vectors.  The other was sorted as it was made.
The problem I am having with the appended code is now it is not finding the duplicates.  It does go through each of the vectors once but for some reason it is not finding the duplicates.  I know there are some because a previous attempt and sorting them out found them though I was running into a serious sigseg fault.

I have been trying to wrap my head around auto and unique and just cant quite get the examples and my (code? methods?) to coincide.

Idzireit

Comment: I am not familiar with the language, but this looks like you fundamentally are using a polynomial time (quartic?) algorithm here (I'm guessing .erase is worst-case linear). Probably, if you want to remove duplicates, you should use something like a hash-set or whatever equivalent data-structure

Comment: @MooingDuck Misleading text, but look at the type: its a vector of vectors, so the "10 numbers" means a "vector of 10 integers."

Comment: Adding to @juanpa.arrivillaga 's suggestion: the equivalent structure in C++ is std::unordered_set. If you made an std::unordered_set< std::vector<int> > out of v2, then checking whether each *v1 corresponded to an element of v2 could be reduced to O(1) time. This might require defining an appropriate hash function for std::vector<int>. You could also use std::set< std::vector<int> >, which does not require a hash function but looks up through binary search (using the lexicographical ordering on std::vector<int>). This is O(log(length of v2)), asymptotically, but can be better in some cases

Comment: Do you need to keep the elements in the same order ? If not, you could copy the last element at position v1 and erase the last element

Comment: If you need to keep the same order: you could 'memorize' the positions that must be erased instead of erasing. Then, a second loop will create (in place) the new vector1 in O(n) operations. Hope not missing the point, rather late here

Comment: It would help if you were allowed to sort both vectors. Then you could use [`std::set_difference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference).

Comment: If the element always contains 10 integers then use std::array instead of std::vector

Comment: @Bob__ I didn't know about `set_difference`, that would have made my answer much shorter!

Comment: Is the number of erasing large or not ? In other words does the erasing process have a significant impact or not ?

Comment: Looking at your recommendation of set difference and linked to set symmetrical difference and I am wondering wouldn't the symmetrical be more appropriate for filtering out the duplicates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm you've selected is O(n²), which means for large data sets it will take a very long time. It's easy to see why you thought it was hung.

If you don't care about ordering, you can sort both vectors to convert this from an O(n²) problem to O(n log n). Once they're sorted you walk through each vector simultaneously, incrementing an index depending on which one is less than the other.

If you can't fit the entire data set into memory at once, you can even use this method by reading from sorted files.

```
bool vec_less(const vector<int>& v1, const vector<int>& v2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < v1.size() && i < v2.size(); i++)
    {
        if (v1[i] < v2[i])
            return true;
        if (v2[i] < v1[i])
            return false;
    }
    return v1.size() < v2.size();
}

std::sort(vector1.begin(), vector1.end(), vec_less);
std::sort(vector2.begin(), vector2.end(), vec_less);
vector<vector<int> >::iterator v1 = vector1.begin();
vector<vector<int> >::iterator v1out = v1;
vector<vector<int> >::iterator v2 = vector2.begin();

while (v1 != vector1.end())
{
    if (v2 == vector2.end() || vec_less(*v1, *v2))
    {
        if (v1out != v1)
            *v1out = *v1;
        ++v1;
        ++v1out;
    }
    else if (vec_less(*v2, *v1))
        ++v2;
    else // equal
    {
        ++v1;
        ++v2;
    }
}
vector1.resize(v1out - vector1.begin());
```

Comment: in the bool function should you check to see if the first elements between v1 and v2 are equal?  Thinking that might return false because the next elements might be true.  Example v1 = 1 2 3 4 .. and v2 = 1 2 4 ....... which would make v1 lesser then v2 but because the first element is equal and not less than therefore would return false.

Comment: `std::vector` already has a `<` that does the same as `vec_less`. The second part of your algorithm is approximately `std::set_difference`

Comment: @Caleth well now that makes two things I didn't know C++ included.

Comment: @idzireit you're absolutely right, that was a big thing to overlook. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 7):

There are <del>two</del> three problems with your solution.

1. Your code has undefined behavior. When you delete item iterator becomes invalid.
2. Your code has large complexity <del>`o(n^2)`</del> `o(n^3)`.
3. Removing item from middle of vector has linear complexity, so for large vectors it should be avoided. This is why I've corrected point `2`.

Code below has `o(n)` time complexity, and use of STL algorithms is usually best choice:

```
using Vec = std::vector<std::vector<int>>;

void removeItems(Vec& from, const Vec& itemsToRemove)
{
    const std::unordered_set<Vec::value_type> items {
       itemsToRemove.begin(),
       itemsToRemove.end()
    };

    auto it = 
    std::remove_if(from.begin(), from.end(),
                   [&items](const auto &x){
                       return items.count(x) != 0;
                   });
    from.erase(it, from.end());
}
```

You can consider replacing internal `std::vector` with `std::array`, since as you describe it has constant size and this will reduce memory fragmentation (what should provide extra boost).

```
using Vec = std::vector<std::array<int, 5>>;
```

Comment: What happens if input vector `from` has duplicate elements ? We have few information  on the scenario targeted by the OP

Comment: Is the order of elements maintained? Sorry for this naive question.  You may indicate it in your answer. We still don't know if it is a constraint

Comment: code provided does exactly same thing what original suppose to do. Use of `unordered_set` allows to make it linear in time. When big data are processed, as described by OP, it will be very fast.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Very interesting. I will apppreciate that the OP tests it and gives a feedback on the performance

Comment: now I noticed another issue with OP code and my. So update should be even faster (if order is not important).

Comment: I asked a question about number of 'erase'. In the comments I proposed a variant of OP solution to stay O(n^2), but your solution should be must faster.